# Recursive way in Prolog

Tags: prolog

How does `intersect(L1,L2,L3)` in second rule work? Can someone trace me through it? Still a beginner in Prolog.

```
intersect([],L,[]).
intersect([A|L1],L2,[A|L3]) :-
   member(A,L2),
   intersect(L1,L2,L3).
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of recursion in programming languages in general? If so, then you just need to understand what the second `intersect/3` clause says: *`[A|L1]` intersect `L2` is `[A|L3]` **if** `A` is a member of `L2` **and** `L1` intersect `L2` is `L3`*. The base case, as with recursion in any languages, gives you a termination condition and result for the recursion. It just says *`[]` intersect `L` is `[]`* for any `L` (which should be written as `_` to avoid the singleton warning and it doesn't matter what `L` is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second rule means:

```
If the head of the first list is present in the second list,
then it is also present in the third.
```

Consider the lists `L1 = [a, b, c]` and `L2 = [d, b]`. We calculate their insection as follows:

```
intersect([a|[b,c]], L2, [a|L3]) :- member(a, L2), intersect([b,c], L2, L3)
```

`a` is not in L2, so this is false. Proceeding:

```
intersect([b|[c]], L2, [b|L3]) :- member(b, L2), intersect([c], L2, L3)
```

`b` **is** in `L2`, so `b` is in the intersection. Proceeding:

```
intersect([c|[]], L2, [c|L3]) :- member(c, L2), intersect([], L2, L3)
```

`c` is not in `L2`, so this is false. Proceeding:

```
intersect([], L2, [])
```

This is the base case. So the intersection is `[b]`.

Comment: The second rule does not mean, *If the head of L1 is present in L2, then it is also present in L3*. `[A|L1]` means that `A` is the head and `L1` is the tail. The correct interpretation of the second rule is in my comment to the OP's question. Or, using your terms, *If the head of `[A|L1]` is present in `L2`, then it is also present in `[A|L3]`*. But that's not quite as clear.

Comment: In that sentence I'm using `L1`, `L2` and `L3` to refer to the original lists, not their "destructured" form, but I'll update my answer to make that more clear.

Comment: But that's out of context. How is the OP supposed to understand that you redefined what these variable names mean? If that's the case, you should write out your version of the predicate so your definition would then make sense. As it stands, there's no other context except the OP's definition of those variables. But, their question was specifically about how the *code they posted* works, so rewriting it even a little stands the chance of adding some confusion.

Comment: Your subsequent example, `intersect([a|[b,c]], L2, [a|L3]) :- ...` uses the OP's definition of `L1` and `L3`, which doesn't match the definition assumed in your explanation of the rule.

Comment: My edited explanation doesn't use variable names at all (edit: the explanatory sentence, not the example).

Comment: That's an improvement.